If a material is homogeneous in $\varepsilon$, can this material be made of different atoms?
I'm currently trying to derive the microscopic expression for the dielectric constant of a material following my proffessor's notes. However, he admits that, even though he assumes $\varepsilon=constant$ throughout his derivation, in the end he "generalizes" the result for a material composed of different atoms (different resonant frequencies, etc.). Nonetheless, wouldn't a material composed of different atoms cease to be homogeneous? It may seem I'm mistaking a homogeneity in chemical composition with a homogeneity in $\varepsilon$, but logic tells me these two are strongly related: different materials will generally have different dielectric constants, so a material with a homogeneous $\varepsilon$ necessarily has a homogeneous chemical composition, or at least it's made of different materials with very similar dielectric constants. But then again, if all the different chemical compounds that form my material have the same dielectric constant, their properties contributing to said constant should also be the same. Is it really valid to generalise the result obtained by my professor? Mathematically, he reaches the conclusion that:
$$\varepsilon = \varepsilon_0 \left(1+\frac{N_vq_e^2}{m\varepsilon_0}\displaystyle\sum_{j=1}^N\frac{f_j}{\omega_{0,j}^2-\omega^2-i\gamma_j\omega}\right)$$
while I claim it should be:
$$\varepsilon = \varepsilon_0 \left(1+\frac{N_vq_e^2}{m\varepsilon_0}\frac{Nf}{\omega_{0}^2-\omega^2-i\gamma\omega}\right)$$
where:

$\omega_0$ is the resonant frequency of the atoms composing my material
$\gamma$ is their friction coefficient (to prevent them from radiating indefinitely. We assume they are Lorentz atoms)
$\omega$ is the frequency of the inciding wave
$N$ is the number of atoms in some volume $\Delta V$ of the material

That is to say, all the terms inside the sum are the same. Could you please tell me whether I am mistaken, and if so, where?

FO glass $SiO_2$? Homogeneity is meant over not within the scale of a few hundred atomic distance. How about pure liquid water, $H_2O$?

and note that atoms/molecules individually do not have dielectric permittivity, an "\epsilon", and it is a many molecules/atoms concept related to the polarizability of individual molecules and their interaction over many many molecules.
